# regex for utf-8 filename validation

Tags: php, regex, filenames

I have been googling around for a couple of hours but I couldn't find a good solution for utf-8 filename validating PHP regex solution. I have tried many of them, if needed I may copy/paste here. File name may include german or other characters but not invalid ones like / etc. Have you got any idea?

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php

Answer (score 1):

One alternative I've always found very elegant is `urlencode()` ing the file names.

That takes away the need to blacklist characters, as it creates file names that work on every file system; showing the real file name is trivial using `urldecode()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try ruling out invalid ones? `^[^/etc]+$` or some such (replace etc with other characters you don't like).

Not sure if you actually need regex for the task.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're trying to validate if a file is UTF-8 or how to do a UTF-8 regex. If you want to do a UTF-8 regex, you can use the `mbstring` series of functions, by first setting [mb_regex_encoding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-regex-encoding.php) to UTF-8, then using [mb_ereg](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg.php) to do the regular expression match. If you want to test if the file has UTF-8, you can use [mb_detect_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) on the file contents and see if it matches UTF-8.